# Angular: router navigate throws JIT compilation failed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In Angular9, I have tried to do a :

```
this.router.navigate(['my-route']);
```

It is defined in my `app-routing.module.ts`

```
  {
    path: 'my-route',
    loadChildren: () => import('./custom/custom.module').then(m => m.CustomModule),
    outlet: 'custom'
  },
```

and

```
CustomModule
```

has the following route:

```
  {
    path: '',
    component: CustomComponent
  }
```

When I trigger the `navigate` I get:

```
Uncaught Error: Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded!
  - JIT compilation is discouraged for production use-cases! Consider AOT mode instead.
  - Did you bootstrap using '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' or '@angular/platform-server'?
  - Alternatively provide the compiler with 'import "@angular/compiler";' before bootstrapping.
```

I actually managed to fix it by adding to my `main.ts`

```
import '@angular/compiler';
```

but I don't know why it fixed it and what side effect it may have. The only difference from a "classic" route is that it lays on a named router outlet.

Comment: The same happened to me in a project using Angular 12.